# setting a limit to a income every 15 minutes error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

ok so this file runs every 15 minutes you get a income, farming and energy bonus at those stages but I don't want them to go over the $storagecap but they don't stop and they keep adding more and more food, gold, energy to your account and never stops.

What I am trying to do is add you income and then if your income goes over $storagecap put your gold to $storagecap but it doesnt work here is my code

```
<?php 
include("functions.php");
connect();
include("user_stats.php");
?>

 <?php
      if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
        include("safe.php");
        include("storagecap.php");?>

<?php
$get_users = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `stats`") or die(mysql_error());

while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_users)) {
  //Get
  $gold = $user["gold"];
  $food = $user["food"];
  $energy = $user["energy"];

  //Increment
  $gold += $user["income"];
  $food += $user["farming"];
  $energy += 5;

  //Verify and correct
  if($energy > 100)
     $energy = 100;

  if($gold > $storagecap)
     $gold = $storagecap;

  if($food > $storagecap)
     $food = $storagecap;

  //Submit
  $update = mysql_query("UPDATE `stats` SET
                    `gold`= '".$gold."',
                    `food`= '".$food."',
                    `energy`= '".$energy."' WHERE `id`='".$user['id']."'") or     die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: get what is there for a given food or gold etc and don't add over it

Comment: the problem with that is you might have 490/500 food and you would never get that 500

Comment: take what they have for food. add what you were going to add into a variable1. (btw you dont need a variable just an if stmt) is it over storagecap? if yes, update setting=storagecap (u got your 500). if no, then update with with what is there plus what you wanted to add (for example you are now at 430

Comment: if it is already at storage cap  (outer if) then dont even get into inner if. when i said "don't add over it" i meant do add over in excess of 'storagecap'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that you are having some syntax problems in your overflow checks.
for one, even if this worked they would have an amount above cap until the next 15 minute round.
For example, let say you had 99 energy, and it added 5, you would now have 104. But the cap check would still have the old values, i.e. 99, and would do nothing. 
Also

```
`gold`=`gold` '$storagecap'
```

is not correct, you need to use

```
`gold`= '".$storagecap."'
```

But to fix the 15 minute delay the best method would be this:

```
<?php
include("functions.php");
include("storagecap.php");
connect();

$get_users = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `stats`") or die(mysql_error());

while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_users)) {
  //Get
  $gold = $user["gold"];
  $food = $user["food"];
  $energy = $user["energy"];

  //Increment
  $gold += $user["income"];
  $food += $user["farming"];
  $energy += 5;

  //Verify and correct
  if($energy > 100)
     $energy = 100;

  if($gold > $storagecap)
     $gold = $storagecap;

  if($food > $storagecap)
     $food = $storagecap;

  //Submit
  $update = mysql_query("UPDATE `stats` SET
                        `gold`= '".$gold."',
                        `food`= '".$food."',
                        `energy`= '".$energy."' WHERE `id`='".$user['id']."'") or     die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

*Please note I have not tested this code, treat it as a rough example*

EDIT:
Just another note, if this query is run, returning energy of, say 99, and it have to fix this to 100, and in another query running at the same time, some energy I used. This might cause this used energy to be "given back". Sorry, I can't explain it better =P Look into MySQL transactions.

Comment: problem is it cleared everyones food and gold but the energy worked it added it up

Comment: What do you mean cleared? At what point? When it hit the storagecap?

Comment: no even when it was at 69 and storage cap was 500 it just put everyones food and gold to 0 but the energy worked it stops at 100 energy

Comment: Well, the it's time to do some quick and dirty debugging. Put a echo of $gold and $food at different points and then open this php page in your browser to see what the values are at the different points. Like after "get", after "increment" etc. to see where it is set to 0. =)


The first thing that hits me is that $storagecap might be 0, since energy works(Not checked against storagecap)

Comment: The file is unaccesibal because it is run via cron_jobs and that makes it a private file it may be help to give you a example of storagecap

<?php

$warehouse = $building['warehouse'];

if ($warehouse == 1) {
 $storagecap = 500;
}elseif($warehouse == 2) {
 $storagecap = 1000;
}elseif($warehouse == 3) {
 $storagecap = 1500;
}elseif($warehouse == 4) {
 $storagecap = 2000;
}elseif($warehouse == 5) {
 $storagecap = 2500;
};
?>

Comment: Try replacing $storagecap with actualy values, like 500 in the chron job code just to see if that might be the problem. I.e:
  if($gold > 500)
     $gold = 500;

  if($food > 500)
     $food = 500;

Comment: Then your problem is in setting $storagecap =) At the end of a elseif chain you should usually have an else to capture any value of $warehouse you did not predict, like if $warehouse is not set or if it's set to a value like 6, 0 or -1 etc. so at the end put else { $storagecap = 10 }   and see if the cap is set to 10, if so that is where your error is.

Comment: ok so now it stops at 10 resources but it is set proberly i have each warehouse = 500 I have 3 warehouses and at the moment it comes up 10/1500 so it knows what $warehouse & $storagecap is

Comment: Then the problem must be in this line: $warehouse = $building['warehouse']; is $building set at this moment? Is $building['warehouse'] correct?; is $warehouse 1 or 500? Check, double check, process of elimination.

Comment: I checked all and they are all in order I updated my code i bit so I will edit the questions post with my new code

Comment: Sorry, then there is nothing more I can help with. You just need to continue to look at $warehouse = $building['warehouse'], as something is happening there. For example, is $warehouse a string "1" or 1?
Good luck!